# Add Button.Content and the click event doen't fire any more on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

My orginal code is:

```
<Button Click="DelClick" ClickMode="Release"></Button>
```

The click event is ok

But when I add an image to the button, the click event doen't work any more

```
<Button Click="DelClick" ClickMode="Release">
   <Button.Content>
        <Image Source="/BackSpaceIcon.png"/>
   </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

I also try another solution but it doesn't work at all

```
<Button>
     <Button.Content>
            <Image Source="/BackSpaceIcon.png" KeyDown="DeleteButtonClick"/>
     </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't reproduce your questions - after adding image to button it's click event is still called, so the error might be somewhere else.

There may be a situation where your click event doesn't bubble up the control hierarchy and gets handled somewhere else. You could try adding MouseLeftButtonUp event on Image instead, but I strongly advise looking what else could've hindered the code.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. :(
I thing there something wrong in my code. I'll try to find out

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem might come from the style of your `Button` control.

If you did not provide a transparent background for your top level panel inside your style, and when you click on the gap between the border of the `Button` and the `Image`, the `Click` event won't fire.